# AfterInterceptor does not work in Grails 3.0.1 anymore

Tags: grails

I noticed that afterinterceptor does not work in Grails 3.0.1 controllers anymore. The same code works in Grails 2.4.4. Here is my controller code:

```
class TestAfterInterceptController {

    def afterInterceptor = { model, modelAndView ->
        println "##################################################"
        println "Current view is ${modelAndView.viewName}"
    }

    def index() {
        println "##################################################"
        render 'Hello world'
    }
}
```

when I call the controller with http://localhost:8080/testAfterIntercept, it completely ingnores the after interceptor method and it only prints what is in the index() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller level interceptors have not been implemented in Grails 3.0 since we have the new `Interceptor` type. See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors

If there is enough demand we will restore controller level interceptors.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to mention it in the Grails 2.x migration to Grails 3 migration documentation because it can potentially break a lot of controllers with no advance notice.

Comment: Also this Quick Reference Guide link still actively refers to afterinterceptors which is a bit misleading. https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html